# Wire type based on transmission voltage?

Tags: cables, high-voltage, transmission-line

I'm trying to calcalte the resistance per km of high voltage transmission lines based on data extracted from OpenStreetMap. I have the transmission voltage and also the length of the wires but I don't have any idea about the material being used (Copper or Aluminum) or the surface area of the wire. Is there any way to estimate the used material and surface based on voltage and length? Thanks

Comment: Before we are able to help you we need to know what you aim for. First of all you want to indicate the power to be transfered and the voltage level involved. Are the lines overhead or subsoil. etc.

Comment: http://www.rd.usda.gov/files/UEP_Bulletin_1724E-200.pdf

Answer (score 2):

"Is there any way to estimate the used material and surface based on voltage and length?

No.
At the very least, you would need to know the design load, and the design losses.

Comment: And probably what regulatory jurisdiction it's in.